# GCC 4.7.2 Optimization Problems

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, optimization

**Summary**

I'm porting ST's USB OTG Library to a custom STM32F4 board using the latest version of Sourcery CodeBench Lite toolchain (GCC arm-none-eabi 4.7.2).

When I compile the code with -O0, the program runs fine.  When I compile with -O1 or -O2 it fails.  When I say fail, it just stops.  No hard fault, nothing (Well, obviously there is something it's doing but I don't have a emulator to use to debug and find out, I'm sorry.  My hard fault handler is not being called).

**Details**

I'm trying to make a call to the following function...

```
void USBD_Init(USB_OTG_CORE_HANDLE *pdev,
           USB_OTG_CORE_ID_TypeDef coreID, 
           USBD_DEVICE *pDevice,                  
           USBD_Class_cb_TypeDef *class_cb, 
           USBD_Usr_cb_TypeDef *usr_cb);
```

...but it doesn't seem to make it into the function body. (Is this a symptom of "stack-smashing"?)

The structures passed to this function have the following definitions:

```
typedef struct USB_OTG_handle
{
  USB_OTG_CORE_CFGS    cfg;
  USB_OTG_CORE_REGS    regs;
  DCD_DEV     dev;
}
USB_OTG_CORE_HANDLE , *PUSB_OTG_CORE_HANDLE;

typedef enum
{
  USB_OTG_HS_CORE_ID = 0,
  USB_OTG_FS_CORE_ID = 1
}USB_OTG_CORE_ID_TypeDef;

typedef struct _Device_TypeDef
{
  uint8_t  *(*GetDeviceDescriptor)( uint8_t speed , uint16_t *length);  
  uint8_t  *(*GetLangIDStrDescriptor)( uint8_t speed , uint16_t *length); 
  uint8_t  *(*GetManufacturerStrDescriptor)( uint8_t speed , uint16_t *length);  
  uint8_t  *(*GetProductStrDescriptor)( uint8_t speed , uint16_t *length);  
  uint8_t  *(*GetSerialStrDescriptor)( uint8_t speed , uint16_t *length);  
  uint8_t  *(*GetConfigurationStrDescriptor)( uint8_t speed , uint16_t *length);  
  uint8_t  *(*GetInterfaceStrDescriptor)( uint8_t speed , uint16_t *length);   
} USBD_DEVICE, *pUSBD_DEVICE;

typedef struct _Device_cb
{
  uint8_t  (*Init)         (void *pdev , uint8_t cfgidx);
  uint8_t  (*DeInit)       (void *pdev , uint8_t cfgidx);
 /* Control Endpoints*/
  uint8_t  (*Setup)        (void *pdev , USB_SETUP_REQ  *req);  
  uint8_t  (*EP0_TxSent)   (void *pdev );    
  uint8_t  (*EP0_RxReady)  (void *pdev );  
  /* Class Specific Endpoints*/
  uint8_t  (*DataIn)       (void *pdev , uint8_t epnum);   
  uint8_t  (*DataOut)      (void *pdev , uint8_t epnum); 
  uint8_t  (*SOF)          (void *pdev); 
  uint8_t  (*IsoINIncomplete)  (void *pdev); 
  uint8_t  (*IsoOUTIncomplete)  (void *pdev);   
  uint8_t  *(*GetConfigDescriptor)( uint8_t speed , uint16_t *length);  
  uint8_t  *(*GetUsrStrDescriptor)( uint8_t speed ,uint8_t index,  uint16_t *length);   

} USBD_Class_cb_TypeDef;

typedef struct _USBD_USR_PROP
{
  void (*Init)(void);   
  void (*DeviceReset)(uint8_t speed); 
  void (*DeviceConfigured)(void);
  void (*DeviceSuspended)(void);
  void (*DeviceResumed)(void);  

  void (*DeviceConnected)(void);  
  void (*DeviceDisconnected)(void);    

}
USBD_Usr_cb_TypeDef;
```

I've tried to include all the source code relevant to this problem.  If you want to see the entire source code you can download it here:  http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/st_prod_software_internet/resource/technical/software/firmware/stm32_f105-07_f2_f4_usb-host-device_lib.zip

**Solutions Attempted**

I tried playing with `#pragma GCC optimize ("O0")`, `__attribute__((optimize("O0")))`, and declaring certain definitions as `volatile`, but nothing worked.  I'd rather just modify the code to make it play nicely with the optimizer anyway.

**Question**

How can I modify this code to make it play nice with GCC's optimizer?

Comment: It is probably the case that turning on optimizations is exposing UB in your code. I.e., your code is probably wrong even with optimizations disabled, you just don't see any symptoms.

Comment: That's a 3.7 MB zip file, I don't thing anyone would debug that for you for free. The code posted is just some declarations and doesn't tell us anything. You should reduce your code to the absolute minimum possible, and try to debug that. Also, have you turned on all warnings, and paid attention to them ?

Comment: Why no emulator? You might want to invest $15 in an STM32F4DISCOVERY board which has an on-board JTAG.  I haven't used one, and I don't know if the Sourcery CodeBench Lite toolchain will work easily with it, but you should be able to get the ST USB OTG library built and running with some toolchain (if not the Sourcery toolchain) and see if you have any problems with your code interfacing to it.

Comment: Looks like Sourcery CodeBench Lite will work well enough with the STM34FDISCOVERY, including the on board emulator: http://andybrown.me.uk/wk/2012/03/31/stm32f4discovery/

Comment: Did you try to check the Reg definitions if it has keywords that doesn't work on GCC?

Comment: I had a similar problem in an NXP USB library, it turned out they were setting a flag from an ISR and waiting for it in a lesser prio context like main or something like this `while(!flag)` but since the flag was not declaired volatile the optimizer made `if(flag){while(1);}` out of it

Comment: GCC does not understand `pragma` directives I think, these are for the MSVC compiler only. Also, do not write/structure your code safety by relying on `volatile` to be respected by the compiler

Comment: When you say that the function body of USBD_Init is not reached: How do you know ? If it's true than it is much more likely the problem is in the code which runs before calling USBD_Init.

Comment: @Dio That's very wrong, `#pragma` is part of the C standard, but each compiler defines *which* pragmas to support. [Here are GCC's pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pragmas.html).

Comment: @unwind I may have been confused, yes. Isn't the use of `#pragma` discouraged by the GCC folk? I had only seen this for code written for MS Visual C, that's why the confusion that it's a windows only thing. Apologies

Comment: Have you run lint or similar on your code? It might find some undefined behavior.

Comment: @Dio: What are you talking about when you say "do not write your code safety by relying on volatile to be respected by the compiler"? It has to be respected by a standards compliant compiler; the only thing I think you could mean is that many people do not understand what volatile does, but that's about it. (hint: volatile means a variable can change without the current thread changing it, so relying on a register cached variable can not be done by the compiler)

Comment: About the safety of volatile, maybe @Dio meant this: "Volatiles Are Miscompiled, and What to Do about It" http://www.cs.utah.edu/~regehr/papers/emsoft08-preprint.pdf

Comment: What i meant to say was that though volatile is there to keep optimizations away, it is not always the case that the code fragment won't be reordered or otherwise optimised by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you showed, so this answer will be more general.

What are typical errors with "close to hardware" code that works properly unoptimized and fails with higher optimization levels?

Think about the differences between `-O0` and `-O1/-O2`: optimization strategies are - among others - loop unrolling (doesn't seem to be dangerous), attempting to hold values in registers as long as possible, dead code elimination and instruction reordering.

improved register usage typically leads to problems with higher optimization levels if hardware registers that can change anytime aren't declared `volatile`properly (see PokyBrain's comment above). The optimized code will try to hold values in registers as long as possible resulting in your program failing to notice changes on the hardware side. **Make sure to declare hardware registers `volatile` properly**

dead code elimination will likely lead to problems if you need to read a hardware register to produce whatever effect on the hardware not known to the compiler and don't do anything with the value you just read. These hardware accesses might be optimized away if you don't declare the variable used for read access `void` properly (compiler should issue a warning, though). **Make sure to cast dummy reads to `(void)`**

instruction reordering: if you need to access different hardware registers in a certain sequence to produce the desired results and if you do that through pointers not related in any way otherwise, the compiler is free to reorder the resulting instructions as it sees fit (even *if* hardware registers *are* properly declared `volatile`). You will need to stray memory barriers into your code to enforce the required access sequence (`__asm__ __volatile__(::: "memory");`). **Make sure to add memory barriers where needed.**

Although unlikely, it might still be the case that you found a compiler bug. Optimization is not an easy job, especially when it comes close to hardware. It might be worth a peek into the gcc bug database.

If all this doesn't help, you sometimes just can't avoid to dig into the generated assembler code to make sure its doing what it is supposed to do.